# How to open app from safari (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, web-applications

I'm trying to write a webapp using swift ,which needs the link from safari. How can I edit the "share" button within the safari, so that I can open my app and get the URL of the current webpage.

Answer (score 1):

The only possibility to share the URL from Safari in/with your app is to use the Share App Extension.

It will look something like this:

[image]

Here is a nice tutorial on how to achieve this: http://www.appcoda.com/ios8-share-extension-swift/